# Связь между записью и id в комментариях

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины, acf

есть страница с формой для отправки отзывов (комментариев). В ней есть поле для id проекта. Есть запись, у этой записи задаётся id(цифра от руки) через ACF. Как можно реализовать связь между отправкой отзыва (комментария) с id записи? Человек при отправке формы указывает id записи и у этой записи оставляется комментарий.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете изменить добавление комментариев с помощью хука `preprocess_comment`:

```
add_filter( 'preprocess_comment', 'my_preprocess_comment' );
function my_preprocess_comment( array $commentmeta ) {
    // Здесь сделайте правильную проверку и замените 777 на нужные ID-поста
    $commentmeta['comment_post_ID'] = 777;

    return $commentmeta;
}
```

Comment: Ну и кого это ответ не устраивает?)